# VB FormatCurrency gives 2 currency symbols

Tags: vb.net, pdftron

I am experiencing extremely weird behaviour with my web .NET application built in VB

The application lists transactions and produces PDF documents with these transactions using PDFTron as the PDF generation tool.

On the front end, the transactions all obey the system currency symbol which can be changed on Region settings. However when the PDF is generated it shows only the British pound symbol. Oddly this is not so when I am debugging on the same server using Visual Studio, only when deployed on IIS regardless if Debug is set to True or False.

**Just to be clear I specifically set the culture using IIS globalization and it works fine. My question is about understanding what could be the cause and why it behaves this way.**

Things to Note:
I have tried setting all settings to United States and US dollar (desired currency) in the machine's control panel, then restarting the machine to see if the settings would take effect, which it didn't. But obviously it is getting this symbol somewhere right?

Application is deployed on Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1.

Comment: Is it only a problem with PDF, or does it also exhibit the same behavior if you output the string in any other way?

Comment: So far I only came across this on the PDF when generated from the deployed version.

Comment: 1) Can you reproduce using one the PDFNet SDK samples, or does this only happen in your project? 2) What do you see when you save the PDF and view in other PDF readers? 3) What is the code for creating the annotation and adding to the PDF? 4) Can you post a screen shot, and clearly indicate what you expected to see?

Comment: 1) Which sample outright will have currency?
2) Same result in other readers
3) I never mentioned annotations